# setting up Image in MKAnnotationPinView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have the following code inside the delegate:

```
     - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)anAnnotation 
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *pin = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: @"RoutePin"];
    if (pin == nil)
    {
        if ([anAnnotation isKindOfClass:[RouteMapAnnotation class]])
        {
            RouteMapAnnotation *theAnnotation = (RouteMapAnnotation *)anAnnotation;
            if (theAnnotation.identifier == @"routePin")
            {
                //NSLog(@"TESTING PART III");
                MKPinAnnotationView *startAnnotationPin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:anAnnotation reuseIdentifier:@"RoutePin"];
                UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
                startAnnotationPin.canShowCallout = YES;
                startAnnotationPin.animatesDrop = YES;

                startAnnotationPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
                startAnnotationPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
                return startAnnotationPin;
            }
            else if (theAnnotation.identifier == @"finishPin")
            {
                NSLog(@"CREATING FINISH FLAG PRIOR");
                MKPinAnnotationView *finishAnnotationPin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:anAnnotation reuseIdentifier:@"FinishPin"];
                finishAnnotationPin.canShowCallout = NO;
                finishAnnotationPin.animatesDrop = YES;
                //finishAnnotationPin.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/formula1/f1_png/128/checkered_flag.png"]]];
                finishAnnotationPin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flag_finish"];
                return finishAnnotationPin;

            }
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

However it's not showing the image for the pin on the map. What am I missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use MKAnnotationView instead of MKPinAnnotationView.

pin annotation is for pins.

Comment: and for the reuseIdentifier? what does that do actually

Comment: reuseIdentifier does the same thing for annotationViews that it does for tableCells... when an annotationView is not on the screen, it gets put in a reuse queue, where you can use it somewhere else, instead of creating more than you need to: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:

Answer (score 0):

Also note that MKPinAnnotationView does offer some additional functionality to a regular MKAnnotationView, such as animating while dragging and the 3d shadow effect. You won't get these if you use MKAnnotationView.

If you want these built-in features, you can create a UIImageView and add it as a subview to your MKPinAnnotationView. This will give you an annotation that looks like whatever you want; but behaves like a pin. I use it to replace the head of the pin with my own images.