# Iphone MapView: Annotation Pin - Different Color

Tags: iphone, annotations, android-mapview

I ask for your advice in solving this issue:

I am fetching a XML File to display Pins on my MapView. In another method I am showing my current position on the map:

```
-(void)setPOIs {

NSLog(@"insert POIs");

int x = 0;

while (x < [res count]) {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D c;
    NSString *latitude = [[res objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"latitude"];
    NSString *longitude = [[res objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"longitude"];
    c.latitude = [latitude doubleValue];
    c.longitude = [longitude doubleValue];
    GPSAnnotation *annotation = [[GPSAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:c];
    annotation.mTitle=[[res objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"ordiname"];
    annotation.currentPoint = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[[res objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"tierarztid"] intValue]];
    annotation.currentRow = [res objectAtIndex:x];
    [mapViewOutlet addAnnotation:annotation];
    [annotation release];

    NSLog(@"latitude setPOIs: %@", latitude);
    x++;
}   

[self showOwn];
```

}

-(void)showOwn {

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D c;
c.latitude = location.latitude;
c.longitude = location.longitude;
GPSAnnotation *annotation1 = [[GPSAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:c];
annotation1.mTitle= @"Ihr Standort";
[mapViewOutlet addAnnotation:annotation1];
[annotation1 release];
```

}

Here I show the pins:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapViewOutlet viewForAnnotation:(GPSAnnotation *)annotation {

int postag = 0;
//int row = 0;

MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
UIButton *myDetailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
myDetailButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 23);
myDetailButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
myDetailButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;


    // Set the image for the button
[myDetailButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_right.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myDetailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showLinks:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 


if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Current Location"]) {
    postag = 99999;
} else {
    postag = [annotation.currentPoint intValue];

} 



myDetailButton.tag  = postag;

// Set the button as the callout view
annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = myDetailButton;

annView.animatesDrop=NO;
annView.canShowCallout = YES;
annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);


return annView;

[annView release];
```

}

What can I do to display a custom image for my current position - and/or not to display a disclosure button?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329575/setting-up-image-in-mkannotationpinview/5329771

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your feedback! I solved by simply adapting an if... else statement

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapViewOutlet viewForAnnotation:(GPSAnnotation *)annotation {

int postag = 0;
//int row = 0;

MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
UIButton *myDetailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
myDetailButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 23);
myDetailButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
myDetailButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;


if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Ihr Standort"]) {
    postag = 99999;
    UIImage *annotationImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"07-map-marker.png"];
    annView.image = annotationImage;
} else {
    postag = [annotation.currentPoint intValue];
    [myDetailButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_right.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myDetailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showLinks:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 

} 



myDetailButton.tag  = postag;

// Set the button as the callout view
annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = myDetailButton;

annView.animatesDrop=NO;
annView.canShowCallout = YES;
annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);


return annView;

[annView release];
```

}

BR,

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `MKPinAnnotationView` use an `MKAnnotationView`. `MKPinAnnotationView` is a subclass of `MKAnnotationView`. The MKPinAnnotationView will ONLY show pins. MKAnnotationView has an image property that you can set to show a different image instead of a pin.

The line of code that is showing the disclosure button is your `rightCalloutAccessoryView` instruction. Take that out and the detail disclosure in the callout will go away.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[ParkingSpot class]])
    {
        static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"ParkAnnotationIdentifier";
        MKAnnotationView* annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:ParkAnnotationIdentifier];
        if (!annotationView)
        {
            MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
            annotationView.draggable = NO;
            UIImage *annotationImage = ...your image here
            annotationView.image = annotationImage;
        }
    return annotationView;
    }
}
```